# Why is my Wordpress website not getting indexed on Google Search Console despite using Yoast SEO and manually creating a sitemap and robots.txt?

Tags: sitemap, google-search, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have added [this website](https://mccannteamcommercial.com/) in my Google Search Console but it's not getting indexed. It's a Wordpress website and I'm using Yoast SEO but since it didn't work out. I had to create Sitemap manually and then upload it to the root of the website as this was suggested by hosting.

Basically, I'm getting error "Couldn't Fetch" for the uploaded sitemap.xml (screenshot attached) and I think it's because High Fail Rate of robots.txt (screenshot attached)

[image]

I never had to touch robots or sitemap while working on Wordpress since Yoast SEO takes care of that mostly but this is the first time I'm facing this issue that's why I had to generate [Sitemap.xml](https://mccannteamcommercial.com/sitemap.xml) and [Robots.txt](https://mccannteamcommercial.com/robots.txt)

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [webmasters.se] instead. SEO questions of any sort are off-topic here. This site is strictly for questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Sorry, just submitted [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142567/why-is-my-wordpress-website-not-getting-indexed-on-google-search-console-despite)